# If / Else statement, how to say "DoNothing" or "Continue"

Tags: c#, .net

I have an IF / ELSE statement, although I would like to know how to tell the "else" part to do nothing if it is true. e.g.:

```
if(x == x) 
 //run calc.exe

else
//DoNothing
```

Or I am write in saying that if I just remove the else statement, it will continue anyway if the if condition is not matched?

Comment: The question is pretty real. It can be semantically meaningful to mark a branch as deliberately empty. More over, it is advised by NUREG TR 6564 to do so in safety critical applications. Just as when we use tabs (or spaces) for indentation, while they are meaningless for the compiler, they improve readability for people. So are empty branches. In Python we have special `pass` statement for it. In C like languages the closest analogy is `{}`.

Answer (score 8):

just omit the else

```
if(condition)
{
   do_something();
}

//go on with your program
```

Comment: Yes, but then you can't easily put a breakpoint on the else situation. Moreover, if you want to document why the "else" part is empty, an explicit DoNothing() command provides an ideal place to put that comment.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. An non existant `else` statement is the same as an empty one.

This is common to all C-like languages.

Answer (score 0):

If there's nothing to do then just omit the `else`:

```
if (some condition)
{
    do stuff
}
```

`continue` is used in loops to short-circuit the rest of the this iteration of the loop and `break` is used to terminate the loop early.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't put an else part and the if condition is not met the program will continue executing its flow:

```
if (SomeCondition)
{
    // Do something if the condition is not met        
}

// continue executing
```